bounded positive definite function
The function $f:\mathcal{R^n}\rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ is said to be positive definite if $f(x)\geq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ if and only if $x={\bf 0}$. The function $f$ is bounded if there exists an $M$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in\mathcal{R}^n$. Does there exist a continuous function that is both positive definite and bounded on $\mathcal{R^n}$?
If it exists I would really appreciate it if you could provide some examples. All examples I have tried so far are one or the other. For example $f(x)=x^2$ is p.d but not bdd. Another example $f(x)=1-\cos{x}$ is bounded but not p.d because $f(2\pi)=0$.

You should restrict your question to continuous or even smooth functions, otherwise, the question is trivial. One could take for instance the function $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus{0}$.

Thank you so much. In my head, I assume continuity. I will edit the question.

$f(x) = \min(1, \Vert x \Vert)$

@Martin R Do you mean $\min$ instead of $\max$?

@MartinR I see, that is also continuous. Such a nice one. Thank you so much.

In the one-dimensional case
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}$$
On $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, consider the function
$$g(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})=f(x_{1})\dots f(x_{n}).$$

I will leave to you the verification of positive definiteness and boundedness. It suffices to achieve that in the one dimensional case.

This is fantastic! Thank you so much.
